# saveToCassandra specify column names in Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark Cassandra Connector to update counters in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.minute_usage_stats (
  metric_date timestamp,
  user_id uuid,
  metric_name text,
  h1_m1 counter,
  h1_m2 counter,
  h1_m3 counter,
  ...
  h24_m60 counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((metric_date), user_id, metric_name)
);
```

The code looks something like this:

```
class Metric(metricName: String, metricDate: Date, userId: String, ???)

metricEventStream
  .map(event => {
    // Parsing logic
    new Metric(metricName, metricDate, userId, h1M1???)
  })
  .saveToCassandra("analytics", "minute_usage_stats")
```

I need to be able to update one counter column at a time and the columns could be different for each item in the map.

Looking through [the documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md), there doesn't seem to be a way to do this without using the Cassandra driver itself and losing all the great functionality of the Spark connector.

Is there any way to specify column names per RDD row with the current Spark Cassandra Connector?

Comment: looks like you are keeping a timeseries by using 24x60 counters. Have you considered using a table to register hits and then use Spark to transform that into this `minute_usage_stats`?  With this model, I'd be in particular worried about replays of data messing up with my counters.

Comment: A change in datamodel could also help. Did you consider: `((metric_date), user_id, metric_name,hour, minute) -> counter`? instead?